# Streaming Currently playing audio to other device Android

Tags: android, audio, rtp

I am working on a application which can play an audio file.
Also if the user wants, they can live stream the audio currently playing without the time lag , so that other users can listen also what one is playing.

I have searched quite about the same on google.
Just got one Example on some blog using **android.net.rtp** package **AudioStream** class

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        AudioManager audio =  (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        AudioGroup audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
        audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL);
        audioStream = new AudioStream(InetAddress.getByAddress(Utilities.getLocalIPAddress()));
        audioStream.setCodec(AudioCodec.PCMU);
        audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_NORMAL);
        //set receiver(vlc player) machine ip address(please update with your machine ip)
        audioStream.associate(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{(byte) 192, (byte) 168, (byte) 1, (byte) 102}), 22222);
        audioStream.join(audioGroup);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Streaming started!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Tried the above sample, but it is not working for me.
Are there any example of AudioStream class or if there is something else i can start with.

Just for concluding..
I want to stream currently playing audio stream from my application over WIFI, so that others listen what i am listening currently.